# Iterating over main menu's items (including subitems)

Tags: delphi, menu, iteration

I'm trying to iterate over all main menu's items. Problem starts at sub menus items. Structure like Menu.Items[i].Items[j].Items[k] doesnt look easy to operate on. Is there any method for that?

---

**My goal** is to list all the items captions.

Comment: what is the goal of iteration? are you trying to find specified item? may be you have to use recursion, may be not. tell us the whole task

Comment: I think i'll have to use recursion on TMenuItem - just came to my mid

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a recursive function like so

```
procedure TForm1.ProcessMenu(AMenu: TMenuItem);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to AMenu.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(AMenu[i].Caption);
    ProcessMenu(AMenu[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProcessMenu(MainMenu1.Items);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this code:

```
USES Menus;

TYPE TItemArr = ARRAY OF TMenuItem;

FUNCTION AllItems(MainMenu : TMainMenu) : TItemArr;
  VAR
    I : Cardinal;

  PROCEDURE Parse(VAR Result : TItemArr ; Item : TMenuItem);
    VAR
      I : Cardinal;

    BEGIN
      SetLength(Result,SUCC(LENGTH(Result)));
      Result[HIGH(Result)]:=Item;
      FOR I:=1 TO Item.Count DO Parse(Result,Item.Items[PRED(I)])
    END;

  BEGIN
    SetLength(Result,0);
    FOR I:=1 TO MainMenu.Items.Count DO Parse(Result,MainMenu.Items[PRED(I)])
  END;
```

Use it as:

```
VAR MI : TMenuItem;
FOR MI IN AllItems(MainMenu) DO ProcessMenuItem(MI);
```